# AIC() and model$aic give different result in mgcv::gam()

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I'm fitting a GAM using mgcv::gam() with spatial smoothes, similar to the model in [this example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/306361/31791) (data [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jscarlton/galvBayData/master/gbtemp.csv)). I've found that using `AIC(model)` gives a different result to `model$aic`. Why is this? Which is correct?

```
library('mgcv')

galveston <- read.csv('gbtemp.csv')
galveston <- transform(galveston,
                   datetime = as.POSIXct(paste(DATE, TIME),
                                         format = '%m/%d/%y %H:%M', tz = "CDT"))
galveston <- transform(galveston,
                   STATION_ID = factor(STATION_ID),
                   DoY = as.numeric(format(datetime, format = '%j')),
                   ToD = as.numeric(format(datetime, format = '%H')) +
                       (as.numeric(format(datetime, format = '%M')) / 60))

knots <- list(DoY = c(0.5, 366.5))
M <- list(c(1, 0.5), NA)
m <- bam(MEASUREMENT ~
         s(ToD, k = 10) +
         s(DoY, k = 30, bs = 'cc') +
         s(YEAR, k = 30) +
         s(LONGITUDE, LATITUDE, k = 100, bs = 'ds', m = c(1, 0.5)) +
         ti(DoY, YEAR, bs = c('cc', 'tp'), k = c(15, 15)) +
         ti(LONGITUDE, LATITUDE, ToD, d = c(2,1), bs = c('ds','tp'), 
            m = M, k = c(20, 10)) +
         ti(LONGITUDE, LATITUDE, DoY, d = c(2,1), bs = c('ds','cc'),
            m = M, k = c(25, 15)) +
         ti(LONGITUDE, LATITUDE, YEAR, d = c(2,1), bs = c('ds','tp'),
            m = M, k = c(25, 15)),
data = galveston, method = 'fREML', knots = knots,
nthreads = 4, discrete = TRUE)

AIC(m)
[1] 57073.08

m$aic
[1] 57053.21
```

Note that the example I've given uses `bam()` instead of `gam()` but the result is the same.

I couldn't replicate this with a simpler model (example from [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mgcv/versions/1.8-34/topics/gam)):

```
set.seed(2) 
dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,dist="normal",scale=2)
b <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),data=dat)

AIC(b)
[1] 1696.143

b$aic
[1] 1696.143
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The discrepancy is because what is stored in `$aic` takes as the degrees of freedom for the complexity correction in AIC is the effective degrees of freedom (EDF) of the model. This has been shown to be too liberal or conservative and can result in AIC always selecting the more complex model or the simpler model depending on whether a marginal or conditional AIC is used.

There are approaches to correct for this behaviour and *mgcv* implements the one of Wood et al (2016), which applies a correction to the degrees of freedom. This is done via the `logLik.gam()` function, which is called by `AIC.gam()`. This also explains the difference as `$aic` is the standard AIC without the correction applied and IIRC is a component of the GAM object that significantly predates the work of Wood et al (2016).

As to why you couldn't replicate this with the simple example, that's because the correction requires the use of components of the fit that are only available when the `method` used to fit is `"REML"` or `"ML"` (including `"fREML"` for `bam()` and also not when the Extended Fellner Schall or BFGS optimizers are used:

```r
> library('mgcv')
Loading required package: nlme
This is mgcv 1.8-34. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.
> set.seed(2) 
> dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,dist="normal",scale=2)
Gu & Wahba 4 term additive model
> b <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),data=dat, method = 'REML')
> AIC(b)
[1] 1698.504
> b$aic
[1] 1696.894
```

where the default for `method` is to use GCV.

#### References

Wood, S.N., Pya, N., Säfken, B., 2016. Smoothing Parameter and Model Selection for General Smooth Models. J. Am. Stat. Assoc. 111, 1548–1563. https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.2016.1180986

Comment: Does this also apply to BIC?

Comment: If the way you are computing BIC is to extract the log likelihood via `logLik` then the DF correction is baked in (assuming the right smoothing parameter selection methods are used). I don't have Simon's book (2017; An Intro to GAMs, 2nd edition) to hand right now, but in there he notes something about BIC and users wanting to check the definition of BIC (the criterion, not the code).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Because calling `BIC()` in R will give the result as calling `AIC()`. I was wondering whether such correction has also been applied to it.

Comment: `BIC()` internally calls `logLik()` and there is a `logLik.gam()` defined by {mgcv}. Simon's comment seems to pertain to the derivation of BIC and is suggesting that that derivation might not be appropriate in some cases (what those are Simon doesn't allude to).